# Calling function of one contract in another using truffle

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, truffle-contract, truffle-test

I have one contract and in it's constructor I have initialized properties of **balances**

```
contract TestChainCoin is RefundableCrowdsale
{
    function TestChainCoin() RefundableCrowdsale() {
            balances[msg.sender] = 100;                                                                   
        }
}
```

The **balances** is described in another contract and this contract have function balanceOf() to return balance.

```
contract StandardToken is Token {
    mapping (address => uint256) balances;

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }
  }
```

Now the problem arise here. I am trying to create test cases in Truffle using javascript and have following code. When I am trying to call balanceOf() then it hits but returns zero amount but I already initialized it to 100.

```
contract('TestChainCoin', function (accounts) {
  let owner = accounts[0];
      it("should TestChainCoin be deployed first", function() {
        return testChainCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        testChainInstance=instance;
        });
      });

     it("should StandardToken be deployed first", function() {
        return standardToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            standTokenInstance=instance;
        });
      });

      it('should return balance of user', async () => {
      let userBal= await standTokenInstance.balanceOf.call(accounts[0]);
      console.log("the balance of user---"+userBal);
      assert(balanceFinal<= 100 && balanceFinal>0, 'balance should not be zero');
      });
```

So where I am doing wrong.

Comment: TestChainCoin is a crowdsale and StandardToken is a token, usually in OpenZeppelin they are separate contracts and they do not share storage.

Comment: so what should be the solution Ismael?

Comment: I can't recommend anything without knowing more about the problem you want to solve. But most crowdsales have the token assignment inside the token contract, or in some class that inherits from StandardToken.